# Self-submiting form redirect

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a php from that includes the external `process.php`, which handles all my validation and sending the `mail` function and submits to it self by setting 
 `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"` 
Everything works great, it validates properly and mails the form to my email, but when I try to include the `header("location: thanks.html")` to redirect after submit, it doesn't redirect. Am I doing this incorrectly or is it an issue with self-submitting the form? I'm also using Jquery and Jquery Mobile. Any help is appreciated

Heres my php

```
<?php 
if(($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =='POST') && (!empty ($_POST['action']))):

if (isset ($_POST['myname'])){$myname=$_POST['myname'];}
if (isset ($_POST['myphone'])){$myphone=$_POST['myphone'];}
if (isset ($_POST['myemail'])){$myemail=$_POST['myemail'];}
if (isset ($_POST['job'])){$job=$_POST['job'];}
if (isset ($_POST['comments'])){
    $comments= filter_var($_POST['comments'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);}

$formerrors = false;



      if($myname === '') :
      $err_myname = '<div class="error"> Sorry, your name is rquired</div>';
      $formerrors=true;
      endif;    

      if($myphone === ''):
      $err_myphone = '<div class="error"> Sorry, your phone number is rquired</div>';
      $formerrors=true;
      endif;    

      if($myemail === ''):
      $err_myemaile =  '<div class="error"> Sorry, your email is rquired</div>';
      $formerrors=true;
      endif;    

      if($job === ''):
      $err_job =  '<div class="error"> Sorry, your business is rquired</div>';
      $formerrors=true;
      endif;    



if (!($formerrors)) :
$to = "myemail@emial.com";
$subject = " Request from $myname --Show and Tell";

$message = "A new show and tell request from:\n
            $myname \n
            $myemail\n
            $myphone\n
            $job\n
            $comments\n";
$replyto = "From: $myemail";


if(mail($to, $subject, $message)):
    $msg ="Thanks for filling out our form";
    header('location: http://localhost/thanks.html');
    else:
    $msg = "There was a problem sending the message";
    endif; //mail data

endif; //check errors

endif; //form submitted

?>
```

And my html

```
<div data-role="content">
<?php if (isset($msg)) { echo '<div id="formmessage"><p>', $msg, '</p> </div>';}?>
<form id="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
  <li data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="myname">Your Name*:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="myname" id="myname" placeholder="John Smith" value="<?php if (isset($myname)) {echo $myname;}  ?>" required/>
    <?php  if (isset($err_myname)) {echo $err_myname;} ?>
  </li>

    <li data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="myemail">Email*:</label><br>
    <input type="email" name="myemail" id="myemail" placeholder="jsmith@email.com" value="<?php if (isset($myemail)) {echo $myemail;}  ?>"  />
    <?php  if (isset($err_myemail)) {echo $err_myemail;} ?>
    <?php  if (isset($err_wrong)) {echo $err_wrong;} ?>
  </li>

    <li data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="myphone">Phone number*:</label><br>
    <input onblur="formatPhone(this);" type="tel" name="myphone" id="myphone" placeholder="1234567890"   value="<?php if (isset($myphone)) {echo $myphone;}  ?>"  required/>
    <?php  if (isset($err_myphone)) {echo $err_myphone;} ?>
  </li>

      <li data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="job">Name of Business*:</label><br>
    <input  type="text" name="job" id="job" placeholder="Where do you work?"   value="<?php if (isset($job)) {echo $job;}  ?>"  required/>
    <?php  if (isset($err_job)) {echo $err_job;} ?>
  </li>


    <li data-role="fieldcontain">
      <label for="comments">Comments:</label><br>
      <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="Questions or Comments?">
      <?php if (isset($comments)) {echo $comments;}?>
      </textarea>

    </li>

<div data-inline="true" data-type="horizontal">
<input name="Reset" type="reset" value="Reset" data-role="button" data-inline="true" />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" data-role="button" 
data-inline="true" name="action" />


</div>


</form>



</div>
```

Comment: set $msg to a $_SESSION variable then pick it up in the receiving page. Just make sure you are calling session_start at the beginning of your script.

Comment: **SIMPLE**: You have `$msg ="Thanks for filling out our form";` **AND** `header('location: http://localhost/thanks.html');`. You can't have both. It's one or the other. You are outputting before header, that's why. Remove one and it will theoretically work. To redirect, remove the line `$msg ="Thanks for filling out our form";`. Let me know how it works out for you, and if yes, then I'll make it as an answer.

Comment: I tried removing `$msg` and just had the header location but it still wouldn't work. It was process the form and mailing it, but not redirecting.

Comment: @user2055617 Either way, you can't have both. You have a problem elsewhere then, which I'll try to find. See if you don't have a whitespace above your `<?php` or outputting HTML before PHP. Plus, please add the `@` symbol in front of my name, if and when you are addressing me.

Comment: I built the form after watch a tutorial (so I could start from somewhere) and the instructor state that using colons was acceptable and you were less likely to get confused than with braces. Any ways, it was a whitespace issue and after removing the whitespace, it redirected fine. Thanks for your help Fred

Comment: @user2055617 Great and you're welcome. I suggest you **accept** Michael Laffargue's answer then, since that's what the problem was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1/ Simple test, are you sure you don't have a whitespace or any other character sent before the `header()`

2/ Did you check you got the http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering option on ? (Else you have to explicitly start output buffering)

Comment: That's what the OP's problem ended up being, and I suggested to accept your answer as being the correct one.

Comment: @Fred Oh thanks, I didn't see the whole discussion over there.